# Weka InfoGainAttributeEval not available

Tags: weka

I need to do feature selection using information gain in learning to rank. I try to use Weka to implement this. But I found in "Select attributes"-"Attribute Evaluator", the "InfoGainAttributeEval" is not available to use. I do not know how to install it and make it available. Anybody knows how to fix this problem?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that something about your dataset is not compatible with the technique you are trying to use.

Although the `InfoGainAttributeEval` entry is greyed out in the list, you should still be able to select it (note the `Start` button is now greyed out), click on its name and then click `Capabilities` which should show you:

> CAPABILITIES
>
> Class -- Binary class, Missing class values, Nominal
>   class
>
> Attributes -- Binary attributes, Date attributes, Empty nominal
>   attributes, Missing values, Nominal attributes, Numeric attributes,
>   Unary attributes

Does your data have attributes that don't match these requirements, or have you selected a class attribute that doesn't match the class requirements?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late reply. I just change another way to do feature selection while I am not familiar with this way